# Setting properties of geoJSON in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I have a map with layers that have similar attributes. I want to add a function that when you select a feature in a layer, it searches for a feature with similar properties in another feature (in this case `NAME`) and if a similar feature property is found, then the styling of the matching feature is altered.

I have a JSfiddle that tries to achieve this here: http://jsfiddle.net/TimLucas/nmd2vsww/6/

The function is called by using the second button. As you can see the `get()` of features works from the function called by the first button.

Here I mainly have problems with how you can set properties (instead of getting them) in the VectorSource GeoJSON file. I use `.attr()` but I am not sure if that actually works.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

There are several errors in your code, namely:

1. Your style functions uses feature.getGeometry().getType(); This will always return "Point" for a Point geometry.

A style function should be something like:

```
var styleFunction1 = function(feature, resolution) {
    if (feature.get("type")) {
      return styles1[feature.get("type")];
    }
    return styles1["Point"];
};
```

2. Your new ol.interaction.Select({}); has no style attribute, this means it will always use the default style for selected features

Pass it a style:

```
select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click,
    style: blueCircle
});
```

3. The find-button callback has several errors:

   - when you find a matching feature, you store it's index in selectArray
   - you should use set() to set a new attribute on a feature

A better function:

```
FindButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if (select) {
            //Get the name of the feature
            var features = select.getFeatures();
            var selectedFeature = features.item(0);
            var name = selectedFeature.get("NAME");
            //Find corresponding name in other layer
            var otherFeatures = Layer2Source.getFeatures();
            for (var i=0; i < otherFeatures.length; i++) {
                var feature = otherFeatures[i];
                if (feature.get("NAME") == name) {
                    feature.set("type", "SelectedPoint");
                } else {
                    feature.set("type", "Point");
                }
            }
        } else {
         window.alert("You have not selected anything");
        }
 });
```

Original answer (for context)

Although I'm not sure how I can get the found features to be redrawn using the same style (i guess you could assign it a new style using feature setStyle (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/apidoc/ol.Feature.html?unstable=true#setStyle)), I've managed to rewrite your code to set the attribute on similar features:

```
var FindButton = document.getElementById('find-sim-name');
FindButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(select) {
            //Get the name of the feature
            var features = select.getFeatures();
            var feature = features.item(0);
            var id = feature.get("NAME");
            //Find corresponding name in other layer

            //this array holds matching features
            var selectArray = [];

            //loop through all features on layer 
            for(var i=0; i < Layer2Source.getFeatures().length; i++) {

                //get the feature
                var feature = Layer2Source.getFeatures()[i];

                //check if name matches
                if(feature.get("NAME") == id){
                    //add matching to the array
                    selectArray.push(feature);
                }
            }
            //Now do something to the found point
            if(selectArray.length > 0){
                for (var j = 0; j < selectArray.length; j++) {
                    var selectedFeature = selectArray[0];
                    selectedFeature.set("type", "SelectedPoint");
                    //perhaps
                    //selectedFeature.setStyle(selectedStyle); 
                }
            }
        } else {
         window.alert("You have not selected anything");
        }
 })r
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser but it seems to me that there are some problems with your solution: 1. You define a new `selectedFeature` var in your last loop and set the value of `type` in that variable, instead of in the source (`Layer2Source`) property. I tried to change this but it still doesn't work. 2. (bit nitpicky this one) you define the `feature` var twice so the second definition is not picked up. The major problem is that I cannot set the new value of the property in the source, do you maybe now how to do this?

Comment: For problem 1) these objects are not copied when assigned to a new variable, the reference is passed. That means that if i loop through Layer2Source, extract feature i, assign it to a variable, push that variable into a new array, and then get it back out from that array and assign it to a new variable it's still the _same_ object as the original one

Comment: As for problem 2: I missed your first defition of feature, but renaming it should be easy..

Comment: Setting a new property on a vector feature is done with set(): http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/apidoc/ol.Feature.html?unstable=true#set

Comment: Well, there where several issues with your jsfiddle: here is my try: http://jsfiddle.net/9vtxch36/

Comment: Yes sorry about that comment, was a little too quick with that. Thanks so much for the solution!!

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again but I really am very new to this. I wanted to do this in my main script where I do not only have `"Point"` types but also `"LineString"` types. With the new type of `stylefunction` this does not work so I wanted to initialize all the sources of the vectors with a for loop (e.g. `for(var i;i<vectorSource.getFeatures().length;i++){vectorSource.getFeatures()[i].set("type", "LineString"}`) but for some reason this does not work, I also tried putting this in `$(document).ready(function(){}` but to no avail. Can you give me some tips on how to do this? Many thanks!

Comment: This however does work when I add this manually to the console...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20301/discussion-between-tim-lucas-and-atlefren).